# jQuery Mobile pagecontainerremove never fires

Tags: jquery-mobile, event-handling

In my multipage jqm document there is a page with the id #internal.  At some point I do

```
$('#internal').remove();
```

The page is removed but

```
$('body').on('pagecontainerremove',function(e,ui){console.log(ui.toPage);console.log('page removed');})
```

does not fire.  Googling for pagecontainerremove and experimenting with various ways of removing the page has not yielded anything useful.

Comment: This event fires only in single page model not multi-page model. To be precise, for uncached external pages (by default). If add `data-dom-cache="true"` to page div of an external page, it will be cached and won't be removed from dom once navigated away.

Comment: Moreover, it looks like a bug in jQM 1.4 `pageremove` fires while `pagecontainerremove` doesn't fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *remove* events `pageremove` and its' "successor" `pagecontainerremove` are fired on *external* pages in *Single Page Model*. jQuery Mobile removes *external* pages from DOM upon navigating away off them. By default, jQuery Mobile doesn't *cache* external pages and binds `bindRemove` to remove them. However, if an *external* page is cached `data-dom-cache="true"`, the *remove* event won't be attached to it to remove it from DOM.

Although `pageremove` is replaced by `pagecontainerremove`, the latter doesn't fire and it is definitely a bug in jQuery Mobile 1.4.

```
/* doesn't fire */
$(document).on("pagecontainerremove", function (e) {
    console.log("pagecontainer event: " + e.type);
});

/* does fire */
$(document).on("pageremove", function (e) {
    console.log("page event: " + e.type);
});
```

> **[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/x1MrXk3xYldz1SvuaexL?p=preview)**

Nevertheless, it is possible to use `bindRemove` in *Multi-Page Model* to let jQuery Mobile removes it once hidden. First, add `data-external-page="true"` to page div that you want to be removed by jQuery Mobile, and then flag it for removal `$("#pageID").page("bindRemove")`.

```html
<div data-role="page" id="pageID" data-external-page="true">
```

```js
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function (e) {
    $(e.target).page("bindRemove");
});
```

> **[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/66bppKDmK7alpAimccBw?p=preview)**