# Jquery Mobile Page Links Causing Duplication

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am building a site using JQuery mobile 1.4.5. It consists of 3 pages (index.html, blog.html, blog-category.html). When the home page loads, there is a link to the blog page. I am using the following code to pass the variables:

```
$.mobile.changePage("blog.html", {
    dataUrl : "blog.html?user=" + travel_user_id,
    data:{ user: travel_user_id },
    transition: "slide",
    reverse: false,
});
```

This works and pulls up the blog page.

On the blog page I have a back button:

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="history.back()" data-direction="reverse" data-transistion="slide" class="back-btn ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-mini ui-btn-inline ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-right">back</a>
```

Which takes you back to the homepage. If I click the blog link again, it slides left twide, so it transitions to the blog page, then transitions again. If I click the back button, then the blog button again, it doubles, so slides left 4 times.

Comment: add data-dom-cache="false" to pages' divs and use data-rel=back instead of history.back().

Comment: more references https://stackoverflow.com/a/26815896/1771795 https://stackoverflow.com/a/26834528/1771795

Comment: I am assuming you mean adding to this div **<div data-role="page">**?

Comment: @Omar I added this, and several of the other recommendations, but still same results.

Comment: Yes, to page div. Have you tried data-external-page="true"? Take a look at console log, check if you have blog page duplicated.

Comment: I added this to the page divs **data-dom-cache="false" data-external-page="true"**, and added this **$(e.target).page("bindRemove")** after **$('#home-page').one('pageshow', function(e, data) {**

Comment: pageshow wont fire and I don't think .page() would work either.